# Generate a new panel containing same check-boxes for each node in treeview VB.NET (Images Attached)

Tags: vb.net, treeview, panel

I want to generate a new panel with a click on each node in a treeview. But this each newly generated panel will have same check-boxes. In addition these check boxes are linked to groupboxes with a checked condition.

I can do this for 4-5 nodes by adding a panel for each node. But I have around 90 such nodes.
Kindly refer following images,
[image: Node1 is selected & check box is clicked]
[image: Node2 is selected]
there are 90 such nodes.

Is there any easier way such as loop etc. to achieve this? or hard way (add panel for each node and use show/hide) is the only way?

Help will be really appreciated.

Cheers,

Comment: 1. What is your question? 2. Why do you need a new panel with every node?

Comment: Each node has same options but each node can have different inputs from these options.e.g: for node1 (A & C may be checked) but for node2 only B may be checked) I want to collect this information for each node.

Comment: Where are you storing the selections?  You can re-use the same panel with every node, just load/save to your underlying storage (such as a list, custom object, database, file, etc.)  This is a common paradigm to separate the model (data) and the presentation (display).

Comment: I am using an excel sheet to store this information. Just to add I am a beginner in VB.NET, so any example or reference will really help.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a loop for this.

This is a sample:

First, you need to define some global variables:

```
Dim Panels(100) As Panel
Dim CheckBox1(100) As CheckBox
Dim CheckBox2(100) As CheckBox
Dim CheckBox3(100) As CheckBox
Dim Label1(100) As Label
```

Then, you should initialize controls on `Form_Load()` event:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To 100

    'Initialize Controls
    Panels(i) = New Panel()
    CheckBox1(i) = New CheckBox()
    CheckBox2(i) = New CheckBox()
    CheckBox3(i) = New CheckBox()
    Label1(i) = New Label()

    'Set properties
    CheckBox1.Left = 100
    CheckBox2.Left = 100
    CheckBox3.Left = 100
    CheckBox1.Top = 100
    CheckBox2.Top = 200
    CheckBox3.Top = 300
    Label1.Left = 100
    Label1.Top = 50
    Label1.Text = "ID : " & NodeNames(i) 'You should replace NodeNames(i) with a variable that you are using for the name of nodes.

    'Add Controls to panel
    Panels(i).Controls.Add(CheckBox1(i))
    Panels(i).Controls.Add(CheckBox2(i))
    Panels(i).Controls.Add(CheckBox3(i))
    Panels(i).Controls.Add(Label1(i))

    'Set visiblity of panel to false
    Panels(i).Visible = False

    'Add panel to the form.
    Me.Controls.Add(Panels(i))       
Next
```

And when you need to show a panel, you should do this:

```
Panels(i).BringToFront()
Panels(i).Visible = True
```

**But having many panels in RAM is not such a good idea. I suggest you to use just one panel and modify it by code for each node. Because if you have many panels and many controls inside it, your application may use a large amount of RAM.**

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed reply. I agree that every new panel will eat my RAM. I tried the other way you suggested but not able to progress. I have added it as a new question with my code and images. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11638467/using-single-panel-containing-checkboxes-for-multiple-treeview-nodes-images-c)