# Using single panel containing checkboxes for multiple treeview nodes (Images & Code Attached)

Tags: vb.net, treeview, panel

I am a VB.NET beginner.

I want to achieve following:

1. Node1 is clicked which opens a panel containing check-boxes.
2. The user will click a few check-boxes.
3. The user clicks node2 which will export check-box information to an Excel sheet column, and reset the panel.
4. New information entered on panel is exported to an adjacent column in the same Excel sheet used in step3.
5. The above process continues for 90 nodes.

How do I do the first part in steps 3, 4 and 5?

This is my first try which is not working:

```
Dim oXL As Excel.Application
Dim oWB As Excel.Workbook
Dim oSheet As Excel.Worksheet
oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Open("F:\open.xlsx")
oSheet = oWB.Worksheets("Sheet1")

'I am not able to think clearly on following loop

For i = 1 To 3
    For j = 1 To 90
        If CheckBox1.Checked Then
            oSheet.Cells(i, j).value = "1"
        Else : oSheet.Cells(i, j).value = "0"
        End If
        If CheckBox2.Checked Then
            oSheet.Cells(i, j).value = "1"
        Else : oSheet.Cells(i, j).value = "0"
        End If
        If CheckBox3.Checked Then
            oSheet.Cells(i, j).value = "1"
        Else : oSheet.Cells(i, j).value = "0"
        End If
    Next
Next

'Following works

CheckBox1.Checked() = False
CheckBox2.Checked() = False
CheckBox3.Checked() = False
ComboBox1.ResetText()
```

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: The Tab key on keyboard is your friend!

Comment: You should **not** use `()` for a property : `CheckBox1.Checked = False`.

Comment: @MahdiThanks for your replies. I am sorry but I did not understand what you mean by Tab key is your friend. Could you please explain it shortly? My level of VB.NET understanding is intermediate.

Comment: I mean `Tab` key, it is a keyboard button for Indenting code. VB.NET is use it automatically (But in your example, there isn't TABs)

Comment: Also I can't what your problem exactly is...

Comment: oh...my code shows tab spaces but while pasting my code I lost the formatting. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you clearly need is a way to store the user's selections in memory, *before* saving them to the spreadsheet. There are several ways you could do this, but given your inexperience I suggest you consider the simplest, which is to define a basic class to represent the user's selections for a single node, and an [array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wak0wfyt.aspx) – where each item is an instance of the class – to store the entire set of user selections.

**Define the node selection class** – to represent selections for a single node:

```
Public Class NodeSelection
    Public CheckA As Boolean
    Public PickAIndex As Integer = -1
    Public CheckB As Boolean
    Public PickBIndex As Integer = -1
    Public CheckC As Boolean
    Public PickCIndex As Integer = -1
    Public ItemProcessed As Boolean
End Class
```

**Define your variables** – in your form class (not in a sub):

```
Private _userPicks(89) As NodeSelection 'Array of user's selections
Private _previousIndex As Integer = -1  'Used to record the previously selected node
```

**Instantiate the array items** – in the form's `Load` event:

```
'Instantiate the class for each element of the array 
For i As Integer = 0 To _userPicks.Count - 1
    _userPicks(i) = New NodeSelection
Next
```

**Keeping track of user selections:**

Whenever a new node is selected, you need to update the array item for the *previously* selected node then reset the controls for the current node. This is best done in the treeview's `AfterSelect` event:

```
Private Sub TreeView1_AfterSelect(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.TreeViewEventArgs) Handles TreeView1.AfterSelect

    'Exit if the click is on the parent node (Node0)
    If e.Node.GetNodeCount(False) > 0 Then Return

    UpdateNodeInfo()

    'If the currently selected node has already been processed, 
    'restore user selection values to the controls,
    'otherwise reset the controls
    With _userPicks(e.Node.Index)
        CheckBox1.Checked = If(.ItemProcessed, .CheckA, False)
        ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = If(.ItemProcessed, .PickAIndex, -1)
        CheckBox2.Checked = If(.ItemProcessed, .checkB, False)
        ComboBox2.SelectedIndex = If(.ItemProcessed, .PickBIndex, -1)
        CheckBox3.Checked = If(.ItemProcessed, .checkC, False)
        ComboBox3.SelectedIndex = If(.ItemProcessed, .PickCIndex, -1)
    End With

    'Color the previous selection so the user can see it's been processed
    If _previousIndex >= 0 Then TreeView1.Nodes(0).Nodes(_previousIndex).BackColor = Color.AntiqueWhite

    'Record this (selected) node's index for updating when the next node is selected
    _previousIndex = e.Node.Index
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateNodeInfo()
    If _previousIndex < 0 Then Return 'No item has been set yet
    With _userPicks(_previousIndex)
        .CheckA = CheckBox1.Checked
        .PickAIndex = If(.CheckA, ComboBox1.SelectedIndex, -1)
        .CheckB = CheckBox2.Checked
        .PickBIndex = If(.CheckB, ComboBox2.SelectedIndex, -1)
        .checkC = CheckBox3.Checked
        .PickCIndex = If(.checkC, ComboBox3.SelectedIndex, -1)
        .ItemProcessed = True 'Record the fact the item has already been processed
    End With
End Sub
```

#### Writing values to the spreadsheet:

Notice that I put the array item update routine in a separate procedure. This is because you will have to update the final selection before writing it all out to the spreadsheet. I presume you will have a button to save their selections, so you just need to call the `UpdateNodeInfo` sub from there before iterating over the array and writing the values. Here is how you might iterate over the values and update the spreadsheet:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To _userPicks.Count - 1
    With _userPicks(i)
        oSheet.Cells(3, i + 2) = "Node" & (i + 1).ToString
        oSheet.Cells(9, i + 2) = "Node" & (i + 1).ToString
        oSheet.Cells(4, i + 2) = If(.ItemProcessed AndAlso .CheckA, 1, 0)
        oSheet.Cells(5, i + 2) = If(.ItemProcessed AndAlso .CheckB, 1, 0)
        oSheet.Cells(6, i + 2) = If(.ItemProcessed AndAlso .checkC, 1, 0)
        oSheet.Cells(10, i + 2) = If(.ItemProcessed AndAlso .CheckA, ComboBox1.Items(.PickAIndex).ToString, "")
        oSheet.Cells(11, i + 2) = If(.ItemProcessed AndAlso .CheckB, ComboBox1.Items(.PickBIndex).ToString, "")
        oSheet.Cells(12, i + 2) = If(.ItemProcessed AndAlso .checkC, ComboBox1.Items(.PickCIndex).ToString, "")
    End With
Next
```

I assume you already know how to open, save and close the spreadsheet, so I'll leave that side of it up to you. Get familiar with the methods outlined here and post another question if you don't.

#### Finally

The above is a fairly simple way to achieve what you're trying to do. If you think you may need to add more functionality to your class, you should look at substituting public members for [properties](http://visualbasic.about.com/od/quicktips/qt/PubClsVar.htm) – some would say you should do that anyway – and you may want to consider storing the complete set of user selections in a [List(Of T)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4kf43ys3.aspx) object rather than an array.

Comment: I cannot thank you enough for such a detailed reply, which is exactly what I needed. Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: No problem. I hope you followed it all okay. It's not complicated but it can appear so if you're unfamiliar with the concepts involved.

Comment: You are spot on. Initially I had similar thoughts but now I am trying to understand it step by step.

Comment: @mrn Good. It's always better to try and understand a process rather than copy-pasting someone else's code and hoping it's exactly right for you. I often rewrite example code after I've worked out what it does, just to be certain I've understood everything properly and can debug later it if necessary.

Comment: I am learning a lot from this code. Just a query, if the number of nodes is a textbox2 input then what will be the change?

Comment: @mrn Instead of declaring the array variable with a literal number in the parentheses, leave the parentheses blank – `Private _userPicks() As NodeSelection` – and use a [`Redim`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8k3cys2%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) statement later to declare the array's size. Use the `Preserve` option if you want to retain existing values.